# undefined reference to main error in gcc on centos.

Tags: gcc, reference, undefined, program-entry-point

I was trying to run a hello world program with gcc using the following command

```
gcc hello.c
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please, add text of hello.c to your post

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that you have no defined a `main()` function in your `hello.c`. Right code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)  /// <<==-- here is a correct definition
{
    printf("Whatever you want\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `return` is missing and the arguments are not obligatory.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to mention, that they are not actually needed. Especially for beginner programmers, which start with `Hello world`, they can be kinda confusing, sometimes :) Anyway, +1, as I would write the same.